# How to add blur node set up to imitate a drop shadow

Tags: animation, node-editor

I'm trying to add a node setup to imitate a drop shadow of my animated line object, but the object appears to be too sharp when I import the PNG sequence into After Effects.

PS: I can't use EEVEE or cycles shadow catcher, my PC can't handle the animation.
And I use Viewport Render Animation to export the PNG sequence.

[image]

https://streamable.com/ehh87d

Comment: Couldn't you do that directly in AE ?

Comment: Yes I could, but since I'm learning Blender 3D, its important for me to learn every aspect of Blender functions, I learn as much possible and gain more knowledge and interest in Blender 3D since I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

put a shader to rgb node in front of the mix shader then plug that in to a color ramp and make sure the mode is set to linear

Comment: This should be the node set up, but its not blurred: and how would it control the opacity ? https://ibb.co/LQksW7q